# multiple tasks for a few threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm using the thread library on c++11 to do some things. The problem is that i have a limited number of threads (4).

I would know how to deal with it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 4

void foo(const std::string& astring)
{
    std::cout << astring << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> list_of_strings(100);
    // values assigned
    std::vector<std::thread> list_of_threads(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
    for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it_string = list_of_strings.begin() ; it_string != list_of_strings.end() ; ++it_string)
    {
        bool check = false;
        unsigned int = 0;
        while(!check) // loop which assigns the next task to the first thread ready.
        {
            if( check = list_of_threads.at(i).ISFREE()) // how to do ?
            {
                list_of_threads.at(i) = thread(&foo,*it_string);
            }
            else
            {
                i = (i + 1) % NUMBER_OF_THREADS;
            }
        }
    }
    for(std::vector<std::thread>::iterator it = list_of_threads.begin() ; it != list_of_threads.end() ; ++it)
        it->join(); // the main thread is waiting for all threads before closing.
    return 0;
}
```

But i don't know how to check if the thread is ready for a new task or not. Any idea ?

Comment: Drew Hall has the best answer so far. Forget about explicitly managing threads with some nasty, (and most likely buggy), 'Thread Manager Loop' and queue up tasks to a pool instead.

Comment: @BradTilley: yeah i'm using it in my code, I just wrote the #define in my question because it is more visible :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual solution is to store the tasks in a shared queue (protected by a mutex and a condition variable) and have each thread check for additional tasks when it completes the current one.  This way each thread stays busy and the rest of the program can remain blissfully ignorant of the allocation.

Comment: Thank you ^^ It seems to be a good idea to store the tasks in a shared queue, but how can I do that ? Is there an example of Thread Manager ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no good built in way. You can either use `std::async` instead of `std::thread` which returns a `std::future` which you can query - this is probably preferable in the general case as it does exactly what you are doing - process work items without the whole overhead of spinning up an OS thread.

Alternatively you can get your thread to signal that its done (say via `std::atomic` or more likely `std::condition_variable`) and then `.join()` it from the main thread to ensure its truly terminated.

Comment: `async` is sorta horrible and probably going to be deprecated for C++14.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Just out of curiosity, why `async` is horrible?

Comment: @Sungmin This is the most blatant problem with `async` http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8951379#8951379.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with std::thread, but assuming there is no better thread class available that has the functionality you need (see Mikes answer perhaps), I would propose writing your own thread class based on std::thread. std::thread would get a function pointer to your own member function, that sets an internal flag that the thread is busy, then calls the function that was provided from outside, then resets said flag. Add a method `IsBusy()` that returns the state of the flag, and you're done.

Comment: Will `IsBusy()` ever provide meaningful information? I can see it providing false positives (the thread stops being busy soon after you ask it) *and* false negatives (the thread is just about to start working and will only set the flag soon after you ask it). (And this is even assuming the flag is an atomic variable)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - yeah, these 'Thread Manager' loops with state-checking are either obviously buggy, non-obviously buggy or, (very rarely), just hopelessly poor performance :((

Comment: Granted, this is by no means a solution ready for usage as is, one would have to spend a considerable amount of time properly implementing and testing such a class. The other answers are probably better suited for the task the Op describes.