# Task.Run() Delay, when first called

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task

I am running a `Thread` which get called in a static interval.
In this `Thread` I am running several `Tasks` (20-200).
All this works fine, but when the `Thread` gets called the first time, it takes like ~1 sec for one `Tasks` to start.
As soon as the `while` loop is in the second loop or when the `Thread` stops, and gets called a second time, the problem is gone.

```
public static async void UpdateThread()
{          
     while(!stop)
     {       
         foreach (DSDevice device in DSDevices)
         {
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Delay is measured here
                // Do Stuff
            });
        }
        //No Delay
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Thread.Sleep(Sleeptime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then `// Do Stuff` is slow. Benchmark it. If you don't show or explain what it does, we can't give any meaningful insights. Is it JIT, I/O, ...

Comment: Tasks (except I/O-bound varieties) utilise a thread from the thread pool.  The pool grows as required.  For all we know you are running 50 threads before the above code runs causing the pool to grow, something that may take a bit of time.

Comment: Yes, //Do Stuff is slow. But it shouldnt really matter. because i'm measuring before it. If i understand it correctly, all of these Tasks should run in parallel, so there is no reason a task is waiting to start, until another is complete. And even if so, why is it only the first time?

Comment: C# is a JIT compiled language. Plus lots of framework code is initialised on first use.

Comment: "Delay is measured here" - how do you do this?

Comment: Did you measure it in Release build, or debug?

Comment: Why are you combining Tasks with Threads? Its better to use each one for their own usage (mostly Tasks as they are the "better" version).

Comment: @KlausGütter: Actual, I'm just writing the progress into the Console. If needed i can measure the exact value.

Comment: @RandRandom Release Build

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328524/are-there-more-tasks-being-performed-than-threads-whats-happening/73328718#73328718 "Are there more tasks being performed than threads? What's happening?") is a possible answer to your question.

Comment: The reason that the threadpool imposes a delay before creating each new thread once a certain limit is exceeded is to avoid the system grinding to a halt as hundreds of threads are created simultaneously by an errant process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Task.Run` runs the code on the `ThreadPool`, and the `ThreadPool` creates initially a limited number of threads on demand. You can increase this limit with the [`SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) method:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 200);
```

...but check out the documentation before doing so. Increasing this threshold is not something that you should do without thinking. Having too many `ThreadPool` threads defeats the purpose of having a pool in the first place. Think whether it's better to have a dedicated thread per device, for the whole life-time of the program.

As a side note, if I was in your shoes I would not parallelize the processing of the devices by creating tasks manually. I would use the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method, which exists for exactly this kind of job. As a bonus it allows to control the degree of parallelism, either to a specific number or to -1 for unlimited parallelism:

```
public static async Task MonitorDevicesPeriodicAsync(
    CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Task delayTask = Task.Delay(MonitorDevicesPeriodMilliseconds);
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1 };
            Parallel.ForEach(DSDevices, options, device =>
            {
                // Do Stuff with device
            });
        });
        await delayTask;
    }
}
```

The `Parallel.ForEach` invokes also the delegate on the `ThreadPool` (by default), and it can saturate it as easily as the `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` approach, so you might need to use the `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` method as well.

Three more off topic suggestions: prefer `async Task` over `async void`. [Async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) is intended for event handler only. Also use a `CancellationToken` for stopping the `while` loop instead of a non-volatile `bool stop` field. In a multithreaded environment, [it's not guaranteed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice) that the mutation of the field from one thread will be visible from other threads. Alternatively declare the field as [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile). Finally use the [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) instead of the `Thread.Sleep`, create the `Task.Delay` task at the start of the iteration and `await` it at the end, for a stable periodic invocation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did change your mind from a "possible" answer to a definite answer? Did you benchmark it and verify that this answer is the reason of the delay 99.9%?

Comment: @RandRandom I don't write 99.9% answers. My answers are closer to 80%. If the answer is wrong, I can edit it later or delete it.

Comment: I typically only give 10%. :) | sorry, if the percentage came of as rude/strange - was just curious since in comment on the question you said "possible“ and wanted to know if you found out that it isn’t only "possible" but in fact the real culprit

Comment: @RandRandom this answer is just intuition. There was no testing involved. I have seen people having similar problems many times.