# Executing same function from several async methods simultenously causes errors

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

Here is a piece of code, where I try to execute different async methods, that need to be executed in specific order (the `await`, and `Task.WhenAll()` parts).

```
//Some other tasks before
Task<bool> taskIfcQuantityArea = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
{
    return this.addGroupStringToDictionary("IfcQuantityArea");
});
Task<bool> taskIfcQuantityLength = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
{
    return this.addGroupStringToDictionary("IfcQuantityLength");
});
Task<bool> taskIfcSiUnit = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
{
    return addGroupStringToDictionary("IfcSiUnit");
});
Task<bool> taskIfcPropertySingleValue = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
{
    return addGroupStringToDictionary("IfcPropertySingleValue");
});
//uses IfcPerson, IfcOrganization
Task<bool> taskIfcPersonAndOrganization = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
{
    return addGroupStringToDictionary("IfcPersonAndOrganization");
});
//uses IfcOrganization
Task<bool> taskIfcApplication = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await taskIfcSiUnit;
    return addGroupStringToDictionary("IfcApplication");
});
//uses IfcSiUnit
Task<bool> taskIfcMeasureWithUnit = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await taskIfcSiUnit;
    return addGroupStringToDictionary("IfcMeasureWithUnit");
});
//some other tasks after.
```

When I do that job synchronously, all works fine, but when I do it in async, I have some random errors. At every test, the errors come randomly.
The only thing I see that could go wrong, is they all execute the same function `addGroupStringToDictionary`.

Here is the function :

```
private bool addGroupStringToDictionary(string typeName)
{
    //int processCount = await Task.Run<int>(() =>
    //{
    GroupedListStrings groupElt = this.listGrouppedStrings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == typeName.ToUpper());
    if (groupElt != null)
    {
        List<string> listStringInGroup = groupElt.ListStrings;
        foreach (string line in listStringInGroup)
        {
            try
            {
                if(typeName== "IfcLocalPlacement($")
                {
                    typeName = "IfcLocalPlacement";
                }
                var type = Type.GetType("Ifc."+typeName);
                if (typeName == "IfcPropertySingleValue" || typeName == "IfcDirection" || typeName == "IfcSiUnit" || typeName == "IfcQuantityLength" || typeName == "IfcQuantityArea" || typeName == "IfcQuantityVolume" || typeName == "IfcQuantityWeight")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, line);
                        this.addToListDictionary((IfcElement)instance);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
                else if (typeName == "IfcOpeningElement")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, line, this.listDictionaries, this.DictionaryBolts);
                        this.addToListDictionary((IfcElement)instance);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, line, this.listDictionaries);
                        this.addToListDictionary((IfcElement)instance);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                this.addError(line);
            }
        }
        this.listGrouppedStrings.Remove(groupElt);
        this.reportProgressImport();
    }
    //return 100;
    //});
    this.reportProgressImport();
    return true;
}
```

The catch got 1-2 times over a bit more than 1 million lines.
At each test the errors come randomly.
Is it possible that running the function simultaneously from several async methods, this is what causes the problem?

Here is the `addToListDictionary` function :

```
private void addToListDictionary(IfcElement elt)
{
    if(elt.ErrorFound)
    {
        this.listReadButError.Add(elt);
        return;
    }
    string type = elt.GetType().ToString();
    if (elt is IfcRepere)
    {
        type = "Ifc.IfcRepere";
    }
    else if (elt is IfcRepereType)
    {
        type = "Ifc.IfcRepereType";
    }
    else if (elt is IfcPhysicalSimpleQuantity)
    {
        type = "Ifc.IfcPhysicalSimpleQuantity";
    }
    else if (elt is IfcProfileDef)
    {
        type = "Ifc.IfcProfileDef";
    }
    else if (elt is IfcGeometricRepresentationContext)
    {
        type = "Ifc.IfcGeometricRepresentationContext";
    }
    GroupDictionary group = this.ListDictionaries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == type);
    if(group==null)
    {
        group = new GroupDictionary { Name = type };
        this.ListDictionaries.Add(group);
    }
    group.ListElements[elt.ID] = elt;

    if (elt is IfcMechanicalFastener)
    {
        IfcMechanicalFastener bolt = (IfcMechanicalFastener)elt;
        this.DictionaryBolts[bolt.Tag] = bolt;
    }
    else if(elt is IfcProject)
    {
        this.listProjects.Add((IfcProject)elt);
    }
    else if(elt is IfcElementAssembly ifcAss)
    {
        this.DictionaryIfcElementAssemblies[ifcAss.Key] = ifcAss;
    }
}
```

Also some additive information about my `ListDictionaries` :

```
private List<GroupDictionary> listDictionaries = new List<GroupDictionary>();
public List<GroupDictionary> ListDictionaries { get { return this.listDictionaries; } set { this.listDictionaries = value; } }
```

And the class `GroupDictionary`

```
public class GroupDictionary
{
    string name { get; set; }
    public string Name { get { return this.name; } set { this.name = value; } }
    public ConcurrentDictionary<int, IfcElement> ListElements = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, IfcElement>();
    public GroupDictionary()
    {

    }
}
```

I made different `GroupDictionary` because as soon as I don't need one of them, I delete it to free space.
I have one dictionary with `IfcPoint`, I need it to gt `IfcPolyLine` (lines), but when I finish to treat all objects using `IfcPoint`, I clear remove the corresponding `GroupDictionary` in order to free some memory.

Comment: 1) What errors? 2) Can you provide a [mre]? 3) clearly there some thread-unsafe operations happening here, for example working with non-concurrent collection from multiple threads. Pretty sure if you change your collections (which we can't see) to their concurrent counterparts (see the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-7.0) namespace)  will solve at least part of the problem (if not entirely).

Comment: @Guru the problem is I cannot set a reproductible example. As I cannot say exactly what is the error, I go in the catch (when I execute the line `object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, line);` (will edit the code with the last modify I did. The problem is over 1M execution, the error comes only 1, maximum 2 times, and everytime different line gives error, I believed that if I executed the `Activor.CreateInstance` 5-10 times simultaneously this can be the problem? `working with non-concurrent collection from multiple threads` This is what I meant. Will have a look at the Concurrent

Comment: _"the error comes only 1, maximum 2 times, and everytime different line gives error,"_ - next time capture the error and add it to the question.

Comment: _"the problem is I cannot set a reproductible example"_ - compilable and runnable exaple would be sufficent.

Comment: @GuruStron I catched : `"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."`, so maybe this is because if my function `addToListDictionary`, I made some calculous, and between the beginning, and the end of the function, the target dictionary has been edited by a competitive async function?

Comment: @Siegfried.V Guru Stron is correct. your `List` is not thread safe. you should keep in mind, concurrency has [its own gotchas](https://i.imgur.com/RbelQBq.png). some described `async`-`await` as *"...the concurrent execution of multiple tasks."* it does not involve actual thread(s), but as your code iterates the `this.ListDictionaries.FirstOrDefault(...` other calls might be already hits the `this.ListDictionaries.Add(group)` - hence, the error message.

Comment: @Guru so you were right, I all changed as the following : I don't have anymore the `GroupDictionary` class, I replaced `private List<GroupDictionary> listDictionaries` by `private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<int, IfcElement>> listDictionaries`, and now the error doesn't appear anymore. Thanks

Comment: @BagusTesa yes in fact, I made the modify as Guru advised and that solved it. I am new on async methods, even didn't know such `ConcurrentDictionary` exists, I guess I need to find a good tutorial about it, cause as I work a lot with 3D, async are very useful to optimize times.

Comment: @GuruStron may I ask you to wite an answer please, explaining what you wrote about `ConcurrentDictionary`, so I could accept, and close the question. Thanks again, was a good lesson for today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a obvious thread-safety issues here (i.e. you are trying to perform some operation which is not thread safe from multiple threads at a time). There are multiple ways you can try tackling it - using [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock)s, or some [synchronization primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives).

But in this case it seems that major source of issues is working with standard collections from multiple threads, which is not thread-safe (because thread-safety usually comes with performance price and is not always needed). You can start from switching to appropriate collections from [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-7.0) namespace.

To go down deeper I recommend free e-book by Joseph Albahari [Threading in C#](https://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. And in fact, changing all to ConcurrentDictionary made operation slower (but it works)

Comment: @Siegfried.V yes, that is why the "default" collections are not thread-safe - thread-safety usually requires some performance cost.

Comment: Again one question please : If I understood, the main problem is the fact that I add items to ListDictionary that makes it unsafe. So in principle, if I create at the beginning that ListDictionary (as I did it in question description), and don't need to create new groups in the function, this may solve the problem?

Comment: @Siegfried.V from what I can assume from the provided code - yes, if you can prefill the dictionary and will not update the same elements from multiple threads - then yes, you can solve the problem. But without full overview of the code it is hard to tell.

Comment: I understand that without the code it's hard to tell, but will try it, thanks again